# Quick way to write multiple if statements

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to create about 100 IF statements like the one below in bulk rather than individually typing each one out with a different value in place of "string". I sometimes use excel to create code but I don't know how to do a line break in a function.

Will IF statements work on a single line, because then excel could be a possibility.

Any help will be much appreciated!

```
if dbread("column").ToString = "string" then
...
else
...
end if



if dbread("column").ToString = "string2" then
...
else
...
end if
```

Comment: Which language are your using currently?

Comment: Visual Basic. I know how to do IF statements but because I need so many I don't want to manually write them all out as they're all only slightly different

Comment: Basically - If string equals then use image1 else image2

Comment: So are you trying to use different images based on some cell's value? You can be bit creative and remove the If condition altogether. If possible, post the exact thing that you want to achieve in each of these IF condition. If there is a pattern ... I might be able to suggest you something easy to use and maintain.

Comment: That's correct. If the string is equal to database value then post image1 (tickbox image blank) else post image2 (tickbox image ticked), the same images throughout. The code for the image is written in DynamicPDF a .NET PDF framework so the code is confusing, but it supports all normal VB code.

Comment: Then why would you need multiple IFs? A single If-Else block should suffice...

Comment: If you need to string together over 100 if statements to accomplish your task, you need to reevaluate your design (such as creating a database table with your strings and a single dynamic if statement). Overuse of If statements is a common design flaw in code. That said, stringing Excel formulas together is the best tool to create repetitive code.

Answer (score 2):

best do a select case.

```
select dbread("column").tostring
case "string"
''do stuff
case "string2"
''do stuff     
case else
''do your else code here
end select
```